# Render turns out grey toned

Tags: rendering, animation, materials, 3d-view

I am beginner and I am trying to animate this scene with some stainless steel cutlery and some blue-ish marble top counter. The view port looks good but when I go to render it the scene looks grey toned and not at all the colours that I wanted. Can someone please help

Here is the
[file](https://gofile.io/d/EheZnq)

Comment: Perhaps you need to add a light…

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Viewport Shading* popover, we can see you disabled the scene world:

[image: viewport shading popover]

So what you saw in your viewport was just the viewport's preview world, the same as in the Material Preview Shading, which is meant for quick shader preview with some quick and easy lighting and reflections.

The scene's world is the only one used when rendering. Any option you set in the viewport popovers affect only the viewport and are meant to be used only for preview purposes.

If you enable the scene world again, you can see your actual render. And that your scene is overall very darkly lit. You could use more or stronger light objects, as well as pump up your scene's world shader.

If you really want to render your viewport as is, switch back to Material Preview, disable the overlays, and use the menu View > Render Image (...):

[image: render image]